# Heroku process failed to Bind port

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to deploy the following starter kit on Heroku. However, when I try to start it, it fails :(

**Error:**

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

I did not find anywhere to configure or set the port. It's launching on 8080 however it still fails.

Browser-sync-server:

```
/**
 * Start browserSync server
 */
'use strict';

const fs    = require('fs');

module.exports = function(options) {

  return () => {
    // If index.html exist - open it, else show folder
    let listDirectory = fs.existsSync(options.mainHtml) ? false : true;

    options.browserSync.init({
      notify: false,
      server: {

        baseDir: './',
        directory: listDirectory
      },
      snippetOptions: {
        // Provide a custom Regex for inserting the snippet
        rule: {
          match: /$/i,
          fn: (snippet, match) => snippet + match
        }
      },
      port: 8080
    });
  };

};
```

`Package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Demo-app",
  "version": "2.3.2",
  "description": "Demo Project",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
  },
  "keywords": [
    "starte",
    "markup",
    "JustCoded",
    "jc"
  ],
  "author": "JustCoded",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.0",
    "browserify": "^16.5.0",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "files-exist": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssimport": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-debug": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-file-include": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-group-css-media-queries": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-htmlhint": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-newer": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "htmlhint-stylish": "^1.0.3",
    "node-notifier": "^5.0.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp build",
    "production": "gulp build",
    "start": "gulp"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "include-media": "^1.4.9",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "normalize.css": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Gulpfile:

```
(() => {
  'use strict';

  const cfg         = require('./gulp-config.js'),
        gulp        = require('gulp'),
        del         = require('del'),
        path        = require('path'),
        notifier    = require('node-notifier'),
        gutil       = require('gulp-util'),
        browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

  /**
   * Require gulp task from file
   * @param  {string} taskName     Task name
   * @param  {String} path         Path to task file
   * @param  {Object} options      Options for task
   * @param  {Array}  dependencies Task dependencies
   */
  function requireTask(taskName, path, options, dependencies) {
    let settings = options || {};
    const taskFunction = function (callback) {
      if (settings.checkProduction) {
        settings.isProduction = process.argv[process.argv.length - 1] === 'build';
      }

      let task = require(path + taskName + '.js').call(this, settings);

      return task(callback);
    };

    settings.taskName = taskName;

    if (!Array.isArray(dependencies)) {
      gulp.task(taskName, taskFunction);
    } else if (dependencies.length === 1) {
      gulp.task(taskName, gulp.series(dependencies[0], taskFunction));
    } else {
      gulp.task(taskName, gulp.series(dependencies, taskFunction));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Remove image(s) from build folder if corresponding
   * images were deleted from source folder
   * @param  {Object} event    Event object
   * @param  {String} src      Name of the source folder
   * @param  {String} dest     Name of the destination folder
   */
  function deleteFile(file, src, dest) {
    let fileName = file.path.toString().split('/').pop();
    let fileEventWord = file.event == 'unlink' ? 'deleted' : file.event;

    let filePathFromSrc = path.relative(path.resolve(src), file.path);
    let destFilePath = path.resolve(dest, filePathFromSrc);

    try {
      del.sync(destFilePath);
      console.log(` \u{1b}[32m${fileEventWord}: ${fileName}\u{1b}[0m`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(` \u{1b}[31mFile has already deleted\u{1b}[0m`);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Show error in console
   * @param  {String} prefix Title of the error
   * @param  {String} err     Error message
   */
  function showError(prefix, err) {
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.white.bgRed(' ' + prefix + ' '), gutil.colors.white.bgBlue(' ' + err.message + ' '));
    notifier.notify({
      title: prefix,
      message: err.message
    });
    this.emit('end');
  }

  /**
   * template HTML
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.fileInclude}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    templates: cfg.fileInclude.templates,
    dest: cfg.fileInclude.dest
  });

  /**
   * Hint HTML
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.htmlHint}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`);

  /**
   * Lint ES
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.esLint}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    src: cfg.folder.src
  });

  /**
   * Build custom js
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.buildCustomJs}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    src: cfg.folder.src,
    dest: cfg.folder.build,
    mainJs: cfg.file.mainJs,
    checkProduction: true,
    showError: showError
  });

  /**
   * Build js vendor (concatenate vendors array)
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.buildJsVendors}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    src: cfg.folder.src,
    dest: cfg.folder.build,
    vendorJs: cfg.file.vendorJs,
    vendorJsMin: cfg.file.vendorJsMin
  });

  /**
   * Build styles for application from SASS
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.buildSass}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    src: cfg.folder.src,
    dest: cfg.folder.build,
    mainScss: cfg.file.mainScss,
    mainScssMin: cfg.file.mainScssMin,
    versions: cfg.autoprefixer.versions,
    checkProduction: true,
    showError: showError
  });

  /**
   * Compile scss files listed in the config
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.buildSassFiles}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    sassFilesInfo: cfg.getPathesForSassCompiling(),
    dest: cfg.folder.build,
    versions: cfg.autoprefixer.versions,
    showError: showError
  });

  /**
   * Build styles for vendor from SASS
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.buildStylesVendors}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    src: cfg.folder.src,
    dest: cfg.folder.build,
    vendorScss: cfg.file.vendorScss,
    vendorScssMin: cfg.file.vendorScssMin,
    showError: showError
  });

  /**
   * Minify images
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.imageMin}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    src: cfg.folder.src,
    dest: cfg.folder.build
  });

  /**
   * Clean build folder
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.cleanBuild}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    src: cfg.folder.build
  });

  /**
   * Clean production folder
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.cleanProd}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    src: cfg.folder.prod
  });


  /**
   * Copy folders to the build folder
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.copyFolders}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    dest: cfg.folder.build,
    foldersToCopy: cfg.getPathesToCopy()
  });

  /**
   * Copy folders to the production folder
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.copyFoldersProduction}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    dest: cfg.folder.prod,
    foldersToCopy: cfg.getPathesToCopyForProduction()
  });

  /**
   * Start browserSync server
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.browserSync}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    mainHtml: cfg.file.mainHtml,
    browserSync: browserSync
  });

  /**
   * Watch for file changes
   */
  requireTask(`${cfg.task.watch}`, `./${cfg.folder.tasks}/`, {
    sassFilesInfo: cfg.getPathesForSassCompiling(),
    src: cfg.folder.src,
    templates: cfg.folder.templates,
    dest: cfg.folder.build,
    imageExtensions: cfg.imageExtensions,
    browserSync: browserSync,
    deleteFile: deleteFile,
    tasks: {
      buildSassFiles: cfg.task.buildSassFiles,
      buildCustomJs: cfg.task.buildCustomJs,
      buildSass: cfg.task.buildSass,
      esLint: cfg.task.esLint,
      fileInclude: cfg.task.fileInclude,
      htmlHint: cfg.task.htmlHint,
      imageMin: cfg.task.imageMin
    }
  }, false);

  /**
   * Default Gulp task
   */
  gulp.task('default', gulp.series(
    cfg.task.cleanBuild,
    gulp.parallel(
      cfg.task.buildCustomJs,
      cfg.task.buildJsVendors,
      cfg.task.buildSass,
      cfg.task.buildSassFiles,
      cfg.task.buildStylesVendors,
      cfg.task.fileInclude,
      cfg.task.htmlHint,
      cfg.task.esLint,
      cfg.task.imageMin
    ),
    cfg.task.copyFolders,
    gulp.parallel(
      cfg.task.browserSync,
      cfg.task.watch
    )
  ));

  /**
   * Creating production folder without unnecessary files
   */
  gulp.task('build', gulp.series(
    gulp.parallel(
      cfg.task.cleanProd,
      cfg.task.cleanBuild
    ),
    gulp.parallel(
      cfg.task.buildCustomJs,
      cfg.task.buildJsVendors,
      cfg.task.buildSass,
      cfg.task.buildSassFiles,
      cfg.task.buildStylesVendors,
      cfg.task.fileInclude,
      cfg.task.htmlHint,
      cfg.task.esLint,
      cfg.task.imageMin
    ),
    cfg.task.copyFolders,
    cfg.task.copyFoldersProduction
  ), true);
})();
```

It's got some issue with Timeout with the binding of the port.

I've added `"preinstall": "npm install -g gulp"` and

My Procfile shows the following as well:

> web: gulp

Can someone help me why it's failing? I really want to deploy this project on Heroku and would very much appreciate any help to solve!

There is no way on the project to bind the port.

Comment: "It's launching on 8080 however it still fails"—you shouldn't be using port 8080 unless that's the port [assigned to you via the `PORT` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers). This is probably fairly straightforward to fix, but we're not going to go and dig through your code on GitHub for you. Questions here should be self-contained to minimize link rot and maximize value for future users. Please copy the part where your server (maybe `express`?) is configured to listen for requests.

Comment: @Chris I totally appreciate your answer. Usually I would look for `package.json` or `app.js` in order to find the port number and changed it. However, in this case `gulp` is generating the port number and couldn't find how it's doing it (I did a google search and then posted repo in case it's useful)

Please let me know how I can fix it.

Comment: @Chris So I found the "Port" section in my browsersync-config. It's 8080, tried changing it to 8000 and even then the same error. Couldn't bind to 8000 in heroku. :(

Comment: _Again_, you _**can't pick your own port on Heroku**_ It doesn't matter if you choose 8000, 8080, or any other value; if _you_ chose it you're using the _wrong_ port. You _**must**_ use the port assigned to you via the `PORT` environment variable. Again, if you edit your question to include the part of your code that listens for connections we might be able to help you solve this.

Comment: @Chris looks like my app isn't listening to any environment variable :(  

  should I add one?

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful @Chris and added the code.

Comment: If your `Procfile` says to just run `gulp` we're going to have to see your `gulpfile.js` too.

Comment: And `browserSync` is a development tool. It shouldn't be used on Heroku. Do you have a production configuration? Something that uses a web server like Express.js?

Comment: @Chris added gulp file (I hesitated to add the code since it's very large but since you asked i added it).  I just want to run browser sync on production (I changed the "Start" in package.json from gulp build (production) to just gulp (development)

Comment: After so many experimentation: Looks like changing the Port: from `8080` to `process.env.PORT || 8080` worked for me. Finally :D able to see UI. Thank you Chris! appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad you got this working. [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark your answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). [Self-answering is encouraged on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Got it. thanks @Chris for pointing that out! Self answered. (Just being thoughtful about other people's time)

Answer (score 0):

Using `process.env.PORT || 8080` instead of just `8080` solved my issue. Heroku likes it this way!